# Label in align environment

Tags: labels

In my project, I make a chapter, a section in a chapter and subsection in a section. Then I  write the equations using align environtment, but the label goes just kind of "(1..1)", I mean the label of the equation is lacked of the number of the section. How can I fix this ? Thanks.

Here is [my project](https://www.overleaf.com/4152128145wyvtnznrwjwv#ac93bf)

Comment: don't make external liks to files that will change, your question here will be archived forever and will not be understandable if the files change, make a small self contained file showing the problem and add it as a code block to your question.

Comment: that said I couldn't see any `align` environments  in your project (I saw several `align*`) don't make people search to find the problem make a simple 1-page example here in the question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see my prop 1.5.2 for instance

Comment: I may look but you should make a document that just has that one alignment and add it here,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes Chef

Comment: that is exactly why you should not reference external projects, make a small self contained example here. But you shpuld never use `alig`n or `align*` for single line equations as here (and don't use `\,=\,` either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so what should I do ?

Comment: sorry I already did more than I would normally do for an external link, but there is no way anyone is likely to debug a massive document to which there is no write access, make a small example here. You changed `\,=\,` to `\ =\ ` which is worse, just use `=` or in align, `&=` but as there is only one row, there is nothing to align

Comment: oh I see what it is I'll post an answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I want to have a small extra spacing between 2 side of the equations, unless it will fell cramped

Answer (score 2):

It is quite unreasonable to post to an external project of that size but as it happens I spotted the issue by eye.

A more reasonable example is

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.}
\begin{document}

\chapter{aaa}

\begin{align}
  a=b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The error is defining `\thechapter` to have a `.` (in your document you also have negative spaces in `\the...` macros!!!!

`report` defines equation numbers by

```
\renewcommand\theequation
  {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@equation}
```

so you get a `.` from the end of `\thechapter` and another `.` to separate the parts.  You could redefine this to use `\arabic{chapter}` instead of `\thechapter` so get a form without the extra `.` (this is what you did for `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`  but a better fix for all of the `\the...counter..` macros would be to define them without a trailing dot and without trailing negative space so that you can use standard forms like `\thesection.\arabic{proposition}` to get propositions numbered by section without getting doubled dots.

Comment: Sir, is there any way that I can keep the dot after the chapter number, and the label of equations in align environment goes like 
```
chapter 1.
section 1.1.
equation (1.1)
equation (1.2)
subsection 1.1.1.
equation (1.1.1)
equation (1.1.2) 
subsection 1.1.2 
equation (1.1.3)
equation (1.1.4) 
section 1.2.
equation (1.3)
equation (1.4)
subsection 1.2.1.
equation (1.2.1)
equation (1.2.2)
```
like so ?

Comment: @PermQi `align` has nothing to do with this, if you used `equation` (which is what you should use for these one line equations), you would see the same. As I say above if you `\renewcommand` `\theequation` replacing `\thechapter` by `\arabic{chapter}` the double . will go that is the simpleset fix from the code you have, although all the code adding . and negative space is wrong really, you don't need to fix that to fix the double dot.

Comment: you mean I change `\renewcommand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}.}` to  `\renewcommand\arabic{chapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}` ?